# Calculating records lost and gained from content build to content build

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that I wrote that essentially finds records present in a new content build that were not present in the previous content build.  I know this works correctly, but now I need to reverse it to find records present in the previous content build that did not make it to the new content build.  Does the second query below accomplish this?

```
select b1.judge_id, count(*) as opinions_gain
from
    (select build_opinion.build_name, judge_id, parse_type, opinion_id, date, new_jdx
    from build_opinion, build_flow
    where build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.previous and judge_id is not null) as b0
right join
    (select build_opinion.build_name, judge_id, parse_type, opinion_id, date, new_jdx
    from build_opinion, build_flow
    where build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.current and judge_id is not null) as b1
on b0.opinion_id = b1.opinion_id
where b1.judge_id != b0.judge_id
group by b1.judge_id
order by opinions_gain desc
;
```

```
select b0.judge_id, count(*) as opinions_lost
from
    (select build_opinion.build_name, judge_id, parse_type, opinion_id, date, new_jdx
    from build_opinion, build_flow
    where build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.previous and judge_id is not null) as b0
left join
    (select build_opinion.build_name, judge_id, parse_type, opinion_id, date, new_jdx
    from build_opinion, build_flow
    where build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.current) as b1
on b0.opinion_id = b1.opinion_id
where b0.judge_id != b1.judge_id
group by b0.judge_id
order by opinions_lost desc
;
```

Also, what would be the most logical way to get more information about those records that are being counted as gained or lost?  Using those queries in a "with, as" subquery?

Table schema of build_opinion (other table, build_flow_moondoor, is simply a table that says what the previous, current, and next build names are):

```
build_name character varying(32),
opinion_id character varying(32),
date timestamp without time zone,
name character varying(32768),
nickname character varying(8192),
docket_number character varying(32768),
parse_type character varying(32),
source_jdx character varying(256),
judge_name_hint character varying(8192),
first_page character varying(1024),
dupe_of character varying(32),
source_id character varying(256),
new_jdx character varying(1024),
court character varying(4096),
judge_id character varying(128),
topic character varying(64),
page_count smallint,
scanned_page_count smallint,
sentences_count smallint,
body_character_count integer,
key_phrase_count smallint,
cited_count integer,
cites_raw_count smallint,
cites_resolved_count smallint,
law_firm_count smallint,
counsels_count integer,
outcome_count smallint,
nature_of_suit smallint,
cause_of_action character varying(256),
CONSTRAINT build_opinion_pkey PRIMARY KEY (build_name, opinion_id)
```

Comment: If I am looking for things missing from one data set that are in another, you have two options, either use `where not exists` or use a `left join` combined with a where clause `where b1.opinion_id is null`

Comment: Are you using MySQL? The `!=` is kind of a hint. Which version?

Comment: @TomC More specifically, I am looking to track movement of opinion_id's from content build to content build.  I'm hoping to see how opinion_id's move from being assigned to one judge_id to another judge_id, build over build.  I want to to track these, as they shouldn't happen in most instances.  Thus, I want these queries to pull all instances where an opinion_id moved from being assigned to one judge_id, to a different judge_id. or instances where an opinion_id went from being assigned to a judge_id, to no judge_id at all.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but can you please add your table schemas - easiest way for people to help is if you post it as create table statements followed by insert statements with some sample data, so we can just paste it into our editors and produce a solution for you. Add an expected result set and you've got it all.

Comment: Are you using a database that does not (yet) supports `full outer join`? "SQL" by itself does not tell us enough. Please **always** use tags to indicate the database as well as "SQL".

Comment: Using Redshift @Used_By_Already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the full outer join for details instead of counts, I suggest these:

/* current build specific */

```
SELECT
    currbuild.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'prevbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.previous
    ) AS prevbuild
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'currbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.current
    ) AS currbuild ON prevbuild.opinion_id = currbuild.opinion_id
WHERE prevbuild.opinion_id IS NULL
;
```

/* previous build specific */

```
SELECT
    prevbuild.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'prevbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.previous
    ) AS prevbuild
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'currbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.current
    ) AS currbuild ON prevbuild.opinion_id = currbuild.opinion_id
WHERE currbuild.opinion_id IS NULL
;
```

/* common items */

```
SELECT
    currbuild.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'prevbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.previous
    ) AS prevbuild
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'currbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.current
    ) AS currbuild ON prevbuild.opinion_id = currbuild.opinion_id
WHERE currbuild.opinion_id = prevbuild.opinion_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little difficult to guess at without the table schemas.

However an attempt based on assumptions that would give you both in the same query is this. This is sql server syntax, I think it will also work in mySQL.

```
;with j as(
    select oc.judget_id as cj, op.Judge_id as pj
    from build_flow f
    join build_opinion oc on oc.build_name=f.current
    join build_opinion op on op.build_name=f.previous
)
select judge_id, sum(gain) as gain, sum(lost) as lost
from 
    (
    select cj as judge_id, count(*) as gain, 0 as lost 
    from j
    where cj<>pj
    group by cj
    union all 
    select pj as judge_id, 0 as gain, count(*) as lost 
    from j
    where cj<>pj
    group by pj
) q
group by judge_id
```

Comment: Inner joins in "J" exclude rows needed for the wanted result.

Comment: How do you know that @Used_By_Already? If the plan is to show where the opinion has changed between previous and current then this works. Difficult to know with the available information. Not sure if `no opinion (previous is null)` to `have opinion (current is not null)` is required. OP might be able to clarify. Easy enough to adjust the second join to `left join` if it is, and add `isnull(pj,'')` to the inequality check in the first union query.

Comment: also,  relation "o" above does not exist, query fails as it stands.

Comment: Thanks @nkramer52. Fixed that. Without table defs and sample data its coding blind.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift supports `full outer join` so I suggest you try this still using 2 subqueries as the sources, e.g.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(prevbuild.judge_id,currbuild.judge_id) judge_id
  , COUNT(case when prevbuild.judge_id = currbuild.judge_id then 1 end) AS opinions_shared
  , COUNT(case when prevbuild.opinion_id IS NULL then 1 end)     AS currbuild_only_options
  , COUNT(case when currbuild.opinion_id IS NULL then 1 end)     AS prevbuild_only_options
FROM (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'prevbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.previous
    ) AS prevbuild
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        build_opinion.build_name
      , COALESCE(judge_id, 'currbuild-null') judge_id
      , parse_type
      , opinion_id
      , date
      , new_jdx
    FROM build_opinion
    INNER JOIN build_flow ON build_opinion.build_name = build_flow.current
    ) AS currbuild ON prevbuild.opinion_id = currbuild.opinion_id
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(prevbuild.judge_id,currbuild.judge_id)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to get opinions lost from one build to another, but the gain column comes up with zeros.

Comment: My mistake. I have fixed the case expression conditions which should test if **opinion_id* is null (*I incorrectly had them testing judge_id originally*)

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  How would you then go about pulling out the data you have counted?  For instance, if I was then interested in diving deeper into a particular opinion_id or judge_id, and seeing how the judge_id associated with an opinion_id has changed from one build to the next.  Or to see a list of opinion_id's that a judge_id has lost or gained?

Comment: To get details just remove the `group by` clause and rework the `select clause` so that you list the wanted columns. In the `where clause`  filter by the judge_id that equates to the condition you need. Otherwise raise another question with **sample data** and **expected result**

Comment: ^counts are off, not sure if my where condition is right.

Comment: I added another answer in case it helps, if it does not help, then - seriously - please ask another question using comments as a way to get further assistance just doesn't work well. Plus you get many others to look at your question and you dont have to wait for me.